# how to add an item to a listView whithout changing other Items

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm beginner in android and i want to add an item to a ListView when i click on a button.
but when i do that , the ListView restarts and all the previous changes i made disappear.
how can i save the previous state of the ListView.

This is the MainActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   listMarks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_marks);
   btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
   final Mark mark = new Mark("", "", "", "");
   final ArrayList<Mark> marks = new ArrayList<Mark>();
   marks.add(marks.size(), mark);
   adapter = new MarkLitViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, marks);
   listMarks.setAdapter(adapter);
   btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         marks.add(mark);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
   });
}
```

[I made this changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26zil.jpg) but when click on add button an item is being add but  previous changes disappear  [this is when i click on the add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoG7y.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I strongly suggest you use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView, if you aren't already. It's a categorically better version of ListView.

The function you are looking for is [notifyItemInserted](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)).

I wrote up a very simple [example](https://pastebin.com/3F1R3znK) in Kotlin (also suggested learning if you want to continue in Android development, since it's the officially supported language now.)

The relevant snippet is below. Create an `addItem` function in your adapter which uses `notifyItemInserted`:

```
fun addItem(value: String) {
    items.add(value)
    notifyItemInserted(items.size)
}
```

And then in your button `OnClickListener` call that adapter function to add a new item.

Comment: i tried and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `adapter.insert(mark, marks.size());` you can use the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` functionality. Remove the final from here `final ArrayList<Mark> marks = new ArrayList<Mark>();` and insert your `Mark` into this ArrayList and then do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() inside the `OnClickListener`

Comment: i tried that but still have the same problem